# Is there a name for a directed graph in which every vertex has outdegree one?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Per the question title, I'm dealing with a number of directed graphs, all of which are 1-out regular, and figure that there is probably a name for such a thing.  Unfortunately, all my search attempts have brought back results about biregular graphs, whereas I am looking for a term that does not constrain indegree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a directed 1-forest, functional graph, or maximal directed pseudoforest. See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoforest

Comment: Of the three terms here, I believe only the term "functional graph" admits (directed) cyclic orbits such as permutations of vertices.