# What's the most precise name for the "forest" of directed graphs of the orbit of a function?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, p-adic-number-theory

What's the most specific name for a collection of directed graphs (possibly cyclic) that maps the orbit of a function?

Can't be a forest or a polyforest because cycles [not allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Polyforest) in trees.  But the correct term isn't jumping out at me.

An example: the graph of the orbit of $x\mapsto p^{-1}\cdot(x-(x\pmod p))$ through the $p-$adic integers.

(Here $x\pmod p$ is the function that maps to the natural number $n$ representative of some element of $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ which is $0\leq n<p$)

This "forest" has uncountably many connected graphs, many cyclic.  The cyclic graphs of period $m$ are enumerated and classified by the base $p$ Lyndon words of length $m$.

Comment: Isn't that just a directed graph? The reason forests have their own name is that trees are required to be connected, and forests are disjoint unions thereof. But a disjoint union of digraphs is again a digraph.

Comment: @Wojowu maybe you're right although there are some extra conditions for the orbit of a function - one and only one edge is directed out of any given vertex. I've amended the question slightly to say that maps the orbit of a function.

Comment: That means out-degree of every vertex is $1$. I am tempted to call such a digraph "out-regular of degree 1" but I'm not sure there is a standard name.

Comment: @Wojowu thanks https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737161/