# Structure closed under unary operation and isomorphism thereof.

Tags: group-theory, set-theory, definition

There are several answers regarding this on the site but none of them seem to be in consensus. Some call it a function, other unoid and some people something else. So I decided to ask it with a example.

Consider the set

$S_1 = \{ 2, 5, 42, 10, 45, 4, 12, 60, 93\}$

and the unary operation

$f_1 : S_1 \to S_1, x \mapsto 26(x^2 +8x)$$\mod 103 $

in other words,

$f_1 (x) = 26(x^2+8x) \mod 103$

As we can see $S_1$ is closed under unary operation $f_1$. So like groups (set closed under binary operation satisfying certain axioms) is there a name for this structure?

Addittionally, let us consider the set

$S_2 = \{2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 55, 37, 1\}$

and the following unary operation:

$f_2 : S_2 \to S_2, x \mapsto 2x$$\mod 73 $,

in other words,

$f_2 (x) = 2x \mod 73$

Since cardinality of both structures are $9$ is it possible that they are isomorphic to each other. If so then how could such isomorphism be found?

Comment: You might be interested in universal algebra.

Comment: For every set $S$ you  can define a (surjective) map $f\colon S\to S$. But with this only, $S$ is left to be just a... set. And we don't say by this that "$S$ is closed under $f$", to my knowledge.

Comment: Let $f_1:X\to X$ and $f_2:Y\to Y$ be bijections and $|X|=|Y|$. The unary algebras $(X,f_1)$ and $(Y,f_2)$ are isomorphic if and only if $f_1$ and $f_2$ have the same cyclic type.

Answer (score 0):

This corresponds to a directed graph with outdegree $1$. (I don't assume the operation to be surjective and/or bijective because the question doesn't say so.) Such graphs are called functional graphs because, yes, this is just a set and a function from that set to that set. Accordingly, you can apply tools for detecting graph isomorphisms to this problem.

Related questions: [Is there a name for a directed graph in which every vertex has outdegree one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737161/is-there-a-name-for-a-directed-graph-in-which-every-vertex-has-outdegree-one) , [What's the meaning of functional graph?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280717/whats-the-meaning-of-functional-graph)